How to fix React infinite rendering loop
I have a relatively simple React view, which currently causes an infinite loop to happen. I try to use useState where ever possible.
Below is the code. it is the component AnvendelsesDisplay that is causing the issue, resulting in the following errors:
 Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. renderWithHooks@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30378:19

import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import BBRMapping from "./BBRMapping";

const AnvendelseDisplay = ({type, anvendelse}) => { 
    const [ a, setA ] = useState(0);
    
    const bbrmap = new BBRMapping();
    const val = bbrmap.MapBBRCode(type, anvendelse);
    setA(val);
    return (
        <>
        <p>Anvendelse: {a}</p>
        </>
    );
}

const ResultsDisplay = (props) => { 

    const hest = props.hest;
    const bbrmap = new BBRMapping();

    return(
        <>
            <Container>
                <h2>Grund</h2>
                <p>Grundareal: {hest.grund.grundareal.grundareal} kvm</p>
                <p>BFE-nummer: {hest.grund.grundareal.bfeNummer}</p>
           </Container>
            {hest.enheder.map((h, i) => {
                return(
                <Container>
                    <h2>Enhed</h2>
                    <p>Enhedensanvendelse: {h.enh020EnhedensAnvendelse}</p>
                    <p>Antal vaerelser: {h.enh031AntalVærelser}</p>
                    <p>Antal badevaerelser: {h.enh066AntalBadev\u00e6relser}</p>
                    <p>Antal vandskyllede toiletter: {h.enh065AntalVandskylledeToiletter}</p>
                    <p>Boligtype: {bbrmap.MapBoligtype(h.enh023Boligtype)}</p>
                    <p>Enhedens samlede areal: {h.enh026EnhedensSamledeAreal}</p>
                    <p>Areal til beboelse: {h.enh027ArealTilBeboelse}</p>
                    <p>Toiletforhold: {bbrmap.MapToiletforhold(h.enh032Toiletforhold)}</p>
                    <p>Badeforhold: {bbrmap.MapBadeforhold(h.enh033Badeforhold)}</p>
                    <p>Koekkenforhold: {bbrmap.MapKoekkenforhold(h.enh034K\u00f8kkenforhold)}</p>
                    <p>Energiforsyning: {bbrmap.MapEnergiforsyning(h.enh035Energiforsyning)}</p>
                </Container>
                )
            })}
            {hest.bygninger.map((h, i) => {
                return(
                <Container>
                    <h2>Bygning</h2>
                    <AnvendelseDisplay 
                        anvendelse={h.byg021BygningensAnvendelse} 
                        type="BygAnvendelse" />
                    <p>Tagdaekningsmateriale: {bbrmap.MapTagdaekningsmateriale(h.byg033Tagd\u00e6kningsmateriale)}</p>
                    <p>Ydervaeggens materiale: {bbrmap.MapYdervaeggensMateriale(h.byg032Yderv\u00e6ggensMateriale)}</p>
                    <p>Samlede boligareal: {h.byg039BygningensSamledeBoligAreal}</p>
                    <p>Varmeinstallation: {bbrmap.MapVarmeinstallation(h.byg056Varmeinstallation)}</p>
                    <p>Opfoerelsesaar: {h.byg026Opførelsesår}</p>
                    <p>Antal etager: {h.byg054AntalEtager}</p>
                    <p>Koordinat: {h.byg404Koordinat} (Koordinatsystem: {h.byg406Koordinatsystem})</p>
                    <p>Bebygget areal: {h.byg041BebyggetAreal}</p>
                </Container>
                );
            })}
        </>
    );
}      

export default ResultsDisplay;

I was unable to get the AnvendelsesDisplay to work properly.
Code for BBRMapping.MapBBRCode() is here:
    MapBBRCode(domain, key) 
    { 
        fetch(`/bbrkode/${domain}/${key}`)
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                        console.log(`MapBBRCode: ${data.value}`);
                        return data.value;
                })

    }


You're setting state on every render:
setA(val);

Updating state triggers a re-render, then your code updates state, which triggers a re-render, which updates state, and so on...
You can use useEffect with an empty dependency array to perform this operation once when the component first loads:
useEffect(() => {
  const bbrmap = new BBRMapping();
  const val = bbrmap.MapBBRCode(type, anvendelse);
  setA(val);
}, []);


Edit: Additionally, now that you've also included the code for MapBBRCode you appear to not actually be returning anything from that function.  Return the Promise from the fetch operation:
return fetch(...

Then in the consuming code you need to either await that Promise or follow it with a .then() callback.  For example:
useEffect(() => {
  const bbrmap = new BBRMapping();
  bbrmap.MapBBRCode(type, anvendelse).then(val => setA(val));
}, []);

or:
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const bbrmap = new BBRMapping();
    const val = await bbrmap.MapBBRCode(type, anvendelse);
    setA(val);
  })();
}, []);


That won't work: OP isn't returning anything from that method, and in addition to the problem you correctly call out as causing the infinite loop, OP seems to be confused about how to return the result of a fetch request.

@JaredSmith: The OP appears to have edited the question after I wrote the answer, though still within the window of not showing an edit history.  Updating...

The reason is simple.
Every time a state changes, react re-renders. Each time the setA(val) runs, react re-renders, causing the code which calls setA(val) to run again, changing the state yet again, which triggers ANOTHER re-render, that runs the code again and again, producing an infinite loop. To fix this, you might want to add a condition that stops that code from running if state a already has a value, that way, you only run the code the first time. You can also change the state in a useEffect with an empty dependency array, like so:
useEffect(() => {
  const bbrmap = new BBRMapping();
  const val = bbrmap.MapBBRCode(type, anvendelse);
  setA(val);
}, []);

